# Pass arguments to a specific test framework when using test-only with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, scalacheck

I've got an SBT project using a couple of test frameworks (ScalaTest and ScalaCheck). For the most part this just works as expected. Eg. running **test** runs both variations of tests.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "org.scalatest"    %% "scalatest"    % "2.2.4"  % "test",
  "org.scalacheck"   %% "scalacheck"   % "1.12.5" % "test"
)
```

However when running **test-only**, when I try to supply an argument to ScalaCheck, ScalaTest steps in and complains:

```
test-only *SomeProp -- -s 10
```

> [error] (test:testOnly) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specifying
>   a suite (-s ) or nested suite (-i ) is not
>   supported when running ScalaTest from sbt; Please use sbt's test-only
>   instead.

In the above example ScalaTest has been invoked with the *-s* argument instead of ScalaCheck.

By looking at the test fingerprints for ScalaTest:

```
superclass is "org.scalatest.Suite" or annotated with: "org.scalatest.WrapWith"
```

and ScalaCheck:

```
superclass is either "org.scalacheck.Properties" or "org.scalacheck.Prop"
```

I assume there should be no confusion on the part of SBT as to which framework to run for a given type of test given the above fingerprints. (*SomeProps variants extend org.scalacheck.Properties.)

Is there some way for me to specify which test framework to invoke with **test-only**? If not do I need to configure SBT to run ScalaTest and ScalaCheck in different configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by creating a separate config for property-based tests (ScalaCheck). I've explained the changes to my build.sbt below.

I kept ScalaTest as the "default" test framework in the **test** config:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "org.scalatest"    %% "scalatest"    % "2.2.4"  % "test"
)
```

I created a separate **prop** config to run ScalaCheck properties. I had to move all my property-based tests from **src/test/scala** to **src/prop/scala**. I also scoped my ScalaCheck dependency to the **prop** config. This made it available only when used in the **prop** config. Similarly, ScalaTest would only be available in the **test** config.

```
lazy val root =
  Project("root", file(".")).
    configs(Prop).
    settings(inConfig(Prop)(Defaults.testSettings)).
    settings(libraryDependencies += scalacheck)

lazy val Prop = config("prop") extend (Runtime)

lazy val scalacheck = "org.scalacheck"   %% "scalacheck"   % "1.12.5" % "prop"
```

And now I can run both ScalaTest and ScalaCheck with arguments without any issues. So basically **test** and **test-only** run ScalaTest while **prop:test** and **prop:test-only** run ScalaCheck.

```
test-only *Spec -- -z "some content" //runs only ScalaTest

prop:test-only *SomeProp -- -s 10 //runs only ScalaCheck
```

More information on how to setup test configurations can be found in the [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html).

The only downside is that I can't run **test** to run all the tests anymore. I have to resort to:

```
;test;prop:test
```

Creating an alias for the above would make things easier.